# vertical alignment of tabular environment inside description environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, description

I am using tabular environment inside a description environment like:

```
\item[This is some description]
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
   apple:       &  200g \\
   pear:        &  206g \\
   banana:      &  114g \\
   orange:      &  150g \\
   grapefruit:  &  350g 
 \end{tabular}

 \lipsum[1]
```

However, the table then is not vertically aligned with the description label (see image).

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Try `\item[This is some description]
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}` (observe added `[t]` at `table`.

Comment: Ah, that was easy, thank you! :)
If you want to make this an answer also explaining the meaning of said parameter `t` I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard form for tabular is

```
\begin{tabular}[pos]{table spec}
```

where `[pos]` is option for position of its baseline: `[t]` at top, `[b]` at bottom and `c` at the vertical center, which is default. For details see [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

In your case, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
\item[This is some description]
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
   apple:       &  200g \\
   pear:        &  206g \\
   banana:      &  114g \\
   orange:      &  150g \\
   grapefruit:  &  350g
 \end{tabular}

 \lipsum[1]
     \end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]